# internal circuitry of IO ports in MCU

Tags: microcontroller, gpio

Could anyone share the internal circuit(transistor level circuit) of GPIO section in a microcontroller?

I am curious to see how a pin can serve as both input or output(of course only one at a time). I understand that there will be switch setting, I would like to see the FET level circuit of the switch indeed!

Comment: Most MCU data sheets have that information!

Comment: Yes, lots of people can.  You could do this yourself too even you had bothered to open the datasheet.

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research

Comment: @MattYoung `Insufficient preliminary research` Why is that a cause to close a question? I don't anywhere is the help center to say "you are not allowed to ask unless you have already searched and were not able to find the answer" (plus we don't know if he has tried). I've seen several simpler questions that could easily be answered with a google search, but no one accused them of having "Insufficient preliminary research". In essence I think it it quite hard to find a question that has no answer already posted somewhere in the interned so almost every question fits that reason to be closed.

Comment: @alexan_e If you want this Stack to be overrun with help vampires, then by all means, allow nonsense like this. Disagree all you want, I will always vote to close questions that show absolutely no research effort.

Comment: Insufficient preliminary research

Comment: V V Rao, I think it would be useful to share your thoughts. What was the reasoning of your question, have you looked in the datasheet of the device you are interested in, wasn't the info you found enough or you had trouble understanding it, are you searching for a more detailed schematic that the ones shown here and in the datasheets...?

Answer (score 15):

Okay, here is a block diagram of a typical microcontroller ([PIC16F616](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41288F.pdf)) I/O pin (Figure 4-1 in datasheet).

Manufacturers do not typically publish transistor-level descriptions of anything complex these days, but we can deconstruct the block diagram with a bit of effort. 
[image]

If you want transistor-level schematics of a D flip-flop, it would be something like this (taken from a 74HC74 datasheet):

[image]

Where the T.G. blocks are transmission gates, similar to CD4016.

[image]

Inverters and gates, you can look up transistor-level schematics in 4000-series CMOS data sheets such as the 4002 4-input NOR.

[image]

Of course on a microcontroller chip there would not be ESD protection networks on internal 
nodes, so that part of the schematic would not be present.

This is all pretty standard CMOS logic. There are two things that are a bit unusual. One is the P-channel transistor marked "Weak" in the GPIO pin block diagram. It is a "Weak" transistor (it has small physical geometry so Idss is only microamperes when it turns on). It is there to act as a pullup current source (similar to a pullup resistor). As you can see, it's only on when selected (/RAPU global weak pullup enable is true), the input is **not** in analog mode, the pin is tristated (on a PIC this means that the pin is an input, so we don't waste pullup current into an output), and WPUA (individual port pin weak pullup enable is true).

The diodes shown are a simplified representation of the GPIO pin protection network.

The other critical thing is the non-inverting buffer driving the I/O pin. It is a tristate buffer. When the pin is selected to be an input (TRISA is true), the buffer output is driven high impedance. The schematic will be something like this part of a MC14503 (minus the input inverter, since the input is an **ENABLE** input not a **DISABLE** input.

[image]

When the ENABLE input is low, both transistor are off, and the pin is no longer driven as an output (on a PIC this occurs when TRISx .. where x is the port number.. is true (HIGH)). A normal inverter has either the "top" (p-channel) or the "bottom" (n-channel) output transistor on at any given time. The tristate buffer has a third state with both transistors off. The fourth possible state (both transistors on, across the power supply) is generally not considered very desirable, and the shown arrangement of gates prevents it from occurring.

That is the only part that gets switched when the pin is selected to be an input or output (see the TRISA output from the latch flip-flop on the top schematic- it only goes to the output buffer enable) . There is no reason to switch the inputs off- they remain connected to the output at all times- since they present negligible load. Similarly, the analog peripherals (if any) are designed so they do not present any load.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a detailed I/O section of an [LPC177x/8x](http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10470.pdf) mcu (page 116).
  I think its operation in input/output mode (as well as several other features) are self-explanatory

[image]