# Is this an accurate model of a microcontroller pin?

Tags: microcontroller, pins, tri-state

For something so common, I can't seem to find anything online on what a microcontroller pin "looks like" (besides a high-level voltage source when output, open-circuit when input). So I decided to just do it myself - let me know what you think. Obviousy specs as per transistor characterstics, pull-up value, etc. aren't important for this.

[image]

Functionality:

1. State (Input or Output):

   - When 0V, input (just like code), Q1 is off and output voltage is disconnected
   - When 3.3V, output (just like code), Q1 is on and output voltage is connected to the pin
2. Output:

   - When 0V, low, outputs 0 volts (duh)
   - When 3.3V, high, outputs 3.3 volts (duh)
   - Only makes it to the pin if state is high
3. Input:

   - High-Input impedance straight into gate
   - If 0V, Q4 is off and so "input" port will read 0V or low
   - If 3.3V, Q4 is on and so "input" port will read 3.3V or high
4. Pull-Up / Pull-Down

   - If they are 3.3V, connects the pin to a pull-up or pull-down resistor.
   - If they are 0V, FET is off and so the resistor is floating there not affecting the circuit

Thoughts? In terms of anything maybe missing / unnecessary. The state and pull-up N-Fets probably aren't necessary - they are just there to make the logic not inverted and the system easier to understand.

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: Slightly more accurate if you use a 4-terminal symbol for Q1 and tie the back gate to vdd instead of to the source.

Comment: [this other EE.SE thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96932/internal-circuitry-of-io-ports-in-mcu) has some relevant info.

Comment: Add some ESD clamp diodes? And you might want to model some series L and shunt C at the pin if you are concerned about SI issues.

Comment: Add in 1 or 2 nanoHenry, for onchip and bondwire and leadframe and PCB traces, at a minimum. And 5pF to 10pF to each of GND and VDD. Note this is a resonant circuit, with unknown dampening. Ringing will happen. What will you do? Your data-eyes will be degraded.

Answer (score 1):

The logical diagram will very depending on the MCU you consider.

The [ATMega328 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) shows a logical diagram of a GPIO pin in section 18.2 you might use as a general introduction.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I figured that - for example, AVR's don't usually have pull-downs but ARM chips do (hence one lacking on the diagram you have.

I wasn't talking about a logical diagram - I meant still at a "somewhat" high-level, how it behaves functionality wise with transistors (output high vs output low vs input vs pull-ups). That is, not worrying about timing / clock / wake-ups / ADC / etc.